# Use flask with pypy on pythonanywhere.com Is it faster setup?

Tags: python, flask, pypy, pythonanywhere

I have small question concerning Flask, pypy and pythonanywhere.com: 
I am developing a small portfolio site for graphic studio; nothing big, only portfolio images are little problem. I use SQLITE for storing information and some ajax calls to retrieve data from SQLITE.

I am curious if adding pypy into the configuration can make things faster; is it worth it? If it is an effective solution, would somebody give me answer as to how to set it up on pythonanywhere.com?

Comment: Deploy both setups and test the speed for your scenario(s)!

Comment: PythonAnywhere developer here -- we don't currently support pypy for websites :-(   If you're looking to speed things up, I'd recommend moving from SQLite to MySQL -- SQLite is slow on PythonAnywhere, MySQL's much faster.

Comment: Hello Giles, thank you very much for your answer:)

Comment: One more question Giles. What about PostgreSQL and speed comparison? I am going to use it in future projects. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: In general, I'd say Postgres > MySQL >> SQLite on PythonAnywhere.

Comment: @GilesThomas You should probably add that as an answer.